# Error: Based on the provided shape, [12544,100], and dtype float32, the tensor should have 1254400 values but has 0

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

While loading my custom model after loading my Mobilenet from my static resource it thorows some exception.

I'm doing it salesforce Where I'm able to save my custom model but when try to load that custom model 'model.json' file it giving some exception.

Here's my code to get model.json in js

```
    let features =  ml5.featureExtractor('MobileNet', modelReady);
    const classifier = features.classification();
    console.log("setup classifier DONE", classifier);

    // A function to be called when the model has been loaded
    function modelReady() {
        console.log('Base Model (MobileNet) Loaded!');
        const load = "{!$Resource.modeljson}";
        console.log('load', load);
        classifier.load(load, customModelReady);
    }

    function customModelReady()
    {
        console.log('Custom model loaded');
    }
```

It gives me the following exception:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCAjM.png)

Please help me, how to resolve this exception.

Comment: Can you share the code of classifier.load ?

Comment: You can see the modelReady(), where after loading the MobileNet model I'm loading my custom model by the static resource.